# How to parse mobile number without special character

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I want to parse a mobile number without special character for example

```
+61-426 861 479 ====>  61 426 861 479
```

PHP preg_match_all

```
preg_match_all('/(\d{2}) (\d{3}) (\d{3}) (\d{3})/', $part,$matches);
if (count($matches[0])){
    foreach ($matches[0] as $mob) {
        $records['mobile'][] = $mob;
    }
}
```

Expected Output

```
+61-426 861 479 ====>  61 426 861 479
```

Comment: Try it like this `\+(\d{2})-(\d{3}) (\d{3}) (\d{3})` https://regex101.com/r/FeOOuJ/1 Or if this is the only string, replace all the non digits `\D+` with a space and use trim.

Comment: This one is already i used its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `+` and the `-` in your pattern. You might update your pattern to use 2 capturing groups and use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). To add the mobile number to the array you could concatenate the first and the second index.

```
\+(\d{2})-(\d{3}(?: \d{3}){2})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xLmwx9/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/kQBoZ)

For example

```
$part = "+61-426 861 478 +61-426 861 479 ";
preg_match_all('/\+(\d{2})-(\d{3}(?: \d{3}){2})\b/', $part, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

if (count($matches)) {
    foreach ($matches as $mob) {
        $records['mobile'][] = $mob[1] . ' ' . $mob[2];
    }
}

print_r($records);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [mobile] => Array
        (
            [0] => 61 426 861 478
            [1] => 61 426 861 479
        )

)
```

If the number is the only string, you might also remove all the non digits using `\D+` and replace with a space. Then use ltrim to remove the leading space from the `+`. See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/LUruF).

Comment: this one is not a correct way to extract a data from document am tried this one is not working

Comment: If the data is in a document you could use the pattern with preg_match_all and get the 2 capturing groups.

Comment: preg_match_all('/(\d{2}) (\d{3}) (\d{3}) (\d{3})/', $part,$matches);
if (count($matches[0])){
    foreach ($matches[0] as $mob) {
        $records['mobile'][] = $mob;
    }
}where i use in above query

Comment: @ArumugamRajamani You are using your original pattern. Try it with the pattern from my answer like this https://3v4l.org/bSqh3

Comment: preg_match_all('/\+(\d{2})-(\d{3}(?: \d{3}){2})\b/', $part, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
                        if (count($matches[0])) {
                            foreach ($matches[0] as $mob) {
                                $records['mobile'][] = $mob;
                            }
                        }                           am struggle in where i concatenate the array

Comment: @ArumugamRajamani I have updated my answer with an example using `preg_match_all`.

Comment: hi bro i have one doubt how to find a name in file